# Example of Artinian module that is not Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I've just learned the definitions of Artinian and Noetherian module and I'm now trying to think of examples. Can you tell me if the following example is correct:

An example of a $\mathbb Z$-module $M$ that is not Noetherian: Let $G_{1/2}$ be the additive subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ generated by $\frac12$. Then $G_{1/2} \subset G_{1/4} \subset G_{1/8} \subset \dotsb$ is a chain with no upper bound  hence $M = G_{1/2}$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module is not Noetherian.

But $M$ is Artinian: $G_{1/2^n}$ are the only subgroups of $G_{1/2}$. So every decreasing chain of submodules $G_i$ is bounded from below by  $G_{1/2^{\min i}}$.

**Edit** In Atiyah-MacDonald they give the following example:

> Let $G$ be the subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of all elements whose order is a power of $p$, where $p$ is a fixed prime.
>   Then $G$ has exactly one subgroup $G_n$ of order $p^n$ for each $n \geq 0$, and $G_0 \subset G_1 \subset \dotsb \subset G_n \subset \dotsb$ (strict inclusions) so that $G$ does not satisfy the a.c.c.
>   On the other hand the only proper subgroups of $G$ are the $G_n$, so that $G$ does satisfy d.c.c.
>
> (Original images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic1Zq.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZK67.png).)

Does one have to take the quotient $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Interesting fact: Artinian rings are Noetherian. [This is not obvious, at least to me.] See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins–Levitzki_theorem).

Comment: You might need to modify the example slightly. $G_{1/4}$ is not a submodule of $G_{1/2}$, so you haven't written down an increasing chain inside of your $M$.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Thanks for pointing this out. So for rings I wouldn't be able to construct such an example. But is the example in my question about modules right?

Comment: @DylanMoreland Thank you! But I meant it the other way around: $G_{\frac12}$ is a subgroup and hence a submodule of $G_{\frac14}$.

Comment: @DylanMoreland For Artinian I want to write down a decreasing chain, no?

Comment: But in this second paragraph you're trying to say that $M = G_{1/2}$ is not Noetherian, and I don't see that. Indeed, it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ so it is Noetherian. I think you're getting at something like Andrea's example.

Comment: In the same direction as Dylan's comment, you might find [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99737/hopkins-levitzki-an-uncanny-asymmetry) interesting.

Comment: @BrunoStonek Thank you!

Comment: @DylanMoreland I'm sorry but I don't understand. The following chain is ascending and is not stationary so $G_{\frac12}$ cannot be Noetherian: $G_{\frac12} \subset G_{\frac14} \subset G_{\frac18} \subset \dots$.

Comment: @ClarkKent What you have is an ascending chain in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @ClarkKent: an ascending chain in $G_{1/2}$ is a set of subgroups $H_i$ of $G_{1/2}$ so that $H_1 \subset H_2 \subset H_3 \subset \cdots G_{1/2}$.  The chain of subgroups you've given shows that neither $\mathbb{Q}$ nor $\mathbb{Q}/G_{1/2}$ is noetherian.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fix a prime $p$ and let $M_p={\Bbb Z}(\frac1p)/{\Bbb Z}$.

It is not difficult to see that the only submodules of $M_p$ are those generated by $\frac1{p^k}+{\Bbb Z}$ for $k\geq0$. From this it follows that $M_p$ is Artinian but not Noetherian.

Comment: Thank you! So $\mathbb Z (\frac{1}{p}) = \{ \frac{k}{p^n} \mid n \in \mathbb N , k \in \mathbb Z \}$?

Comment: Right! I think that it can be described as the smallest divisible submodule of ${\Bbb Q}/{\Bbb Z}$ containing $1/p$.

Comment: Do we have to quotient by $\mathbb Z$? Does it not work with subgroups of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @ClarkKent: $A=\mathbb{Z}(\frac1p)$ is not artinian, as it contains the decreasing sequence of subgroups $A \supset qA \supset q^2A \supset q^3A \supset \cdots$ for any prime $q\neq p$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Right, thank you very much. I'm starting to understand it a bit better.

Comment: @AndreaMori Can submodules of $M_p$ not be generated by $\frac{1}{pq} + \mathbb Z$ for a different prime $q$?

Comment: $\frac1{pq}+\Bbb Z$ does not even belong to $M_p$, see your own description of $M_p$ in the first comment.