# Noetherian rings have only finitely many minimal prime ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, noetherian

We say that $p$ is minimal prime if It does not contain any other prime.

Assume that $A$ is Noetherian ring

Question: $A$ has only finitely many minimal primes.

any suggestions please

Comment: A bit more context might help here. $\qquad$

Comment: The answer is yes, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525640/how-to-prove-a-commutative-with-unit-noetherian-ring-a-only-has-finitely-man) for example.  I am not sure what the nicest proof is.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an approach you might try:

A topological space $X$ is called *Noetherian* if it satisfies the ascending chain condition on open sets.  Equivalently, every collection of open sets has a maximal element.  A topological space $Y$ is said to be *irreducible* if it is not the union of two proper closed sets.

If $R$ is a ring with identity, then the set $\textrm{Spec } R$ of prime ideals of $R$ is a topological space whose closed sets are of the form $$V(I) := \{ \mathfrak p \in \textrm{Spec } R : I \subseteq \mathfrak p \}$$ for $I$ an ideal of $R$.

1 .  A maximal irreducible subset of a topological space $X$ is called an *irreducible component.*  They always exist by Zorn's lemma.  Show that a Noetherian topological space has only finitely many irreducible components.

2 .  Show that the mapping $I \mapsto V(I)$ gives an order reversing bijection between *radical* ideals of $R$ and closed sets of $\textrm{Spec } R$.  Show that under this bijection, prime ideals are in bijective correspondence with irreducible closed sets.  In particular, minimal prime ideals correspond to maximal irreducible sets.

3 .  Show that if $R$ is a Noetherian ring, then $\textrm{Spec } R$ is a Noetherian topological space.